# Fontification of custom LaTeX macro

Tags: auctex

I have defined a macro `\mpunct{...}` which I would like to be displayed in the same face as `\mbox{...}` is (i.e. green, not red as the rest of the text in math mode).

I don't know if it matters, anyway, `\mbox` is in the class `"function"` in `font-latex.el`.

Do I have to define my own keyword class, or is it better to add it to the list "function"?

Also, do I have to set it in my `.emacs` or is it possible to do it in a style file?

Comment: I should have pointed out that I use `color-theme-solarized`, hence the colors mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with the following code in one's `.emacs` file:

```
;; Fontify some macros
(setq font-latex-user-keyword-classes
      ;; Make <\macroname> display with the same face as \mbox.
      ;; \mbox is classified as "function" in font-latex.el and as such it uses the face font-lock-function-name-face.
      '(("my-function"  (("macroname" "{")) font-lock-function-name-face command)))
```

See
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/326706/efficiently-highlight-known-math-macros-in-auctex
https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Fontification-of-macros.html